# Retirar caracteres específicos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minha dúvida é o seguinte, neste trecho de codigo estou retirando um caractere que especifico com o `replace()`:

```
lista = [["de carlos,"],["des.dd carlossd,"],["Peixe, texto!"]]
lista_separados = ['.',',',':','"','?','!',';']



for i, j in enumerate(lista):
   lista[i] = j[0].replace(',','').replace('!','').replace('.','')

print (lista)
```

saída:

```
['de carlos', 'des dd carlossd', 'Peixe texto']
```

neste exemplo consegui eliminar os caracteres especificados, mas

alguém tem alguma ideia de realizar isto de uma outra maneira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra maneira de fazer é usando [translate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm), que:

```
lista = [["de carlos,"],["des.dd carlossd,"],["Peixe, texto!"]]
lista_separados = ['.',',',':','"','?','!',';']

trans = {ord(i): '' for i in lista_separados} # mapear codigo ascii de cada caracter para o seu substituto, neste caso nada...    
for idx, val in enumerate(lista):
   lista[idx][0] = val[0].translate(trans)
print(lista) # [['de carlos'], ['desdd carlossd'], ['Peixe texto']]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MPTz)

Não sei porque tens uma lista de listas, secalhar precisas mesmo, mas caso contrário podes simplesmente fazer com uma lista de uma dimensão:

```
lista = [["de carlos,"],["des.dd carlossd,"],["Peixe, texto!"]]
lista_separados = ['.',',',':','"','?','!',';']

trans = {ord(i): '' for i in lista_separados}
lista = [j.translate(trans) for i in lista for j in i]
print(lista) # ['de carlos', 'desdd carlossd', 'Peixe texto']
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MPTz/2)

NOTA que também podes passar `None` em vez de string vazia: `{ord(i): None for ... }`

Comment: Eu tenho uma lista de listas, porque cada sublistas é referente a um conteúdo de um arquivo[i].txt da base documentos com varios arquivos.txt, entendeu?     legal esse jeito que vc explicou! não conhecia...

Comment: @WilliamHenrique nesse caso a primeira alternativa é a adequada. De nada, ainda bem que ajudei

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar *Expressões Regulares*

> Talvez tenha um jeito ainda melhor para fazer isso, alguém com mais experiência no assunto.

Vou mostrar duas opções, a primeira deixa apenas letras, números e espaços.

```
import re

lista = [["de carlos,"],["des.dd carlossd,"],["Peixe, texto!"]]
for i, j in enumerate(lista): lista[i] = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', re.sub(r'\.', ' ', j[0]))

print (lista)
```

> Veja funcionando no [repl](https://repl.it/MPGT/1)

Pensando eu, caso você queria manter um *Ponto final* que esta em uma frase, e não  um `.` que esteja no meio de uma palavra, e qualquer outro caractere especial.

```
import re

lista = [["Esse, ponto! vai permanecer, porque e um ponto final. Agora esses.pontos.serao.substituidos.por.espacos.porque.esta no@ meio¨&*() das #palavras"]]

for i, j in enumerate(lista): lista[i] = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 .]', '', re.sub(r'\.\b', ' ', j[0]))

print (lista)
```

> Veja funcionando no [repl](https://repl.it/MPGX/2)